# Undefined variable in views

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am making a PostController and getting data from posts table

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Posts;

class PostController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    $posts=Posts::latest()->paginate(5);
    // print_r($posts);exit;
    return view('post.index',compact($posts))
    ->with('i',(request()->input('page',1)-1)*5);
}
```

and my view page code is

```
    @foreach($posts as $post)

    <?php echo $post->title; ?>
    @endforeach
```

It's giving me Undefined variable Post in views.
My model code is:-

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posts extends Model
{
     protected $fillable=['title','description'];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue in your code.

You may have to write like this for rendering data to view.

> return view('post.index',compact($posts))
>       ->with('i',(request()->input('page',1)-1)*5);
>   From above , to below . change the code.
>   return view('post.index',compact('posts'))
>       ->with('i',(request()->input('page',1)-1)*5);

It will work.

Comment: @vivek modi, if the answer is correct and helped you, please mark it as correct.

Comment: Yes i will but stackoverflow didn't allow me to mark it as correct before 10 minutes so as soon as possible i get chance to mark it as correct i will do that

Comment: Ahh, my apologies, I didn't realize it was answered so fast.